# In Github, can I run a python script from a different repo than where it's stored?

Tags: python, github

Let's say I have a a repo that has a python script stored in it, then another repo where I want to run that script, such as below within repo1.

```
sh "python repo2/src/python.py --arg value --arg2 value2"
```

I'm sorry. I know this seems like a simple question, but I either don't know how to phrase my question or else it's just not possible.

Thank you.

More info:
The script is part of a repo and this is where it needs to live, especially to stay modular. The other repo is a for a pipeline and it has a groovy Jenkinsfile. This is where I want to pull that script and run in within the Jenkinsfile

Comment: Can you provide additional context? What is this script? What is the environment you wish to run it in?  The answer to your question will probably be one of "your architecture with multiple repos seems flawed" or "make one a pypi package required by the other" depending on the answers to these questions.

Comment: I've added more context. Thanks @BowlingHawk95

Answer (score 0):

You can write a bash script that moves into the desired directory for you and executes the file from there.
Let's say you want to execute program2.py in another directory from where you actually want to call it, then you could write a simple bash script to do this for you:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd path/to/dir/where/program2.py/is/stored
python program2.py --arg value
```

Save this bash script with a .sh file ending. Then just make it executable with `chmod +x` and make sure it's in the same directory as the directory where you want to execute it, of course, and you should be good to go!

Answer (score -2):

let's say you have a python script that is reading text files you can excecute the code
as it follows and it will work

```
python /dir/to/your/file.py /dir/to/another_file.txt
```

Comment: The crux of his problem is that the script he wants to run lives in a different code repository than where he wants to invoke it.  So unless you happen to clone the repos next to each other and then invoke a file path (very fragile), this won't help.